# Additional Disk Space

Tags: hard-drive, mount

I try to add additional disk space

```
[root@vps62868 ~]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda    252:0    0  40G  0 disk
└─vda1 252:1    0  20G  0 part /
vdb    252:16   0  50G  0 disk
```

the disk space at the moment

```
[root@vps62868 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G   19G  306M  99% /
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
```

now I mount the additional disk with these commands

```
mkdir -p /mnt/vdb
mkfs.ext4 /dev/vdb
mount /dev/vdb /mnt/vdb
```

now I have this disk space

```
[root@vps62868 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G   19G  311M  99% /
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vdb         50G   52M   47G   1% /mnt/vdb
```

okay looks good but now if I restart the server disk space is again

```
[root@vps62868 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G   19G  306M  99% /
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
```

Do I have to save something I don't get it?

Comment: type `man fstab` into your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add it to `/etc/fstab` in order for it to mounted during boot. Add something like this:

```
/dev/vdb  /mnt/vdb    ext4     defaults    1   2
```

`man fstab` will explain the meaning of the fields.

NB: Adding space like that will most likely not fix your issues on `/`, as this is nearly full and mounting an additional drive will do nothing to fix this. You could extend `/` for another 20GB if you resize the partition `/dev/vda1` and grow the filesystem there.

Comment: So I wrote in /etc/fstab UUID=51ba13e7-398b-45f3-b5f3-fdfbe556f62c / ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=2e4a9012-bf0e-41ef-bf9a-fbf350803ac5 /mnt/vdb ext4 nofail 0 0